# firefox 70 lockPref not working

Tags: 18.04, firefox

I want to set manual proxy configuration and lock them in the latest firefox 70 on Ubuntu 18.04, so that others should not modify it. Created `user.js` and added

```
lockPref("network.proxy.http","127.0.0.1")
lockPref("network.proxy.http_port","8080")
```

but the `lockPref` is not working in the firefox 70, and settings are getting locked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user.js` is not used for locking preferences.

[Locking preferences](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Lock_Prefs) at MozillaZine Knowledge Base.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response and worked